# Getting a 'not a statement' error with script

Tags: java

I am trying to work out why this script wont work. I am trying to create a script that will let me generate a random number and when the program is finished i can choose whether to re run it or not. BUt everytime i compile it i get an 'not a statement' error. Even if i delete String continue it still gives me this error.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Loopers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String
        continue = "yes";
        Scanner getInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (
        continue.equals("yes") ) {

            Random r = new Random();
            int numOfRandoms;
            System.out.println("Enter a number");
            numOfRandoms = getInput.nextInt();

            int[] randomNum = new int[100];

            for (int x = 1; x < numOfRandoms; x++) {
                randomNum[x] = r.nextInt(100);
                System.out.println(randomNum[x]);
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Do you wish to run the program again? Yes or No.");
            getInput.nextLine();
            continue = getInput.nextLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is invalid code, `continue` is a keyword in Java and you can't name a variable like that:

```
String continue = "yes";
```

Try renaming it everywhere to something else, for example:

```
String cont = "yes";
```